# Matplotlib set_drawstyle doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I noticed something weird. When I make a link chart with drawstyle parameter, it works. For example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(10, 24, 10)
y = np.random.randn(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.plot(x, y, drawstyle="steps")
```

However, if I want to set it with, say,

```
ax.lines[0].set_drawstyle('steps')
```

It does not work at all. Instead a line without steps is shown.

Any clues?

Comment: Because someone voted to close this because of a missing [mcve], I just want to note that this is reproducible by using just any values for `x` and `y`.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I openend [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10338) about it.

Comment: Same behaviour when adding the line manually: `line = lines.Line2D(x,y); line.set_drawstyle('steps'); ax.add_line(line); ax.relim(); ax.autoscale_view()`. If `ax.add_line` is done *before* `set_drawstyle`, the steps are not shown.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I cannot reproduce your last comment. Independent of the order of commands, `Line2D` produces the desired result for me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, I saw your github issue and was wondering about that. Anyway with my backend (MacOSX), I have the same problem as with the `plot` command. I also tried using `plt.Line2D` instead of `lines.Line2D` -- same thing. In connection also with the other github issue you opened yesterday, I'll create an account over there and add that information, but I'm not sure if I have time today -- seems there are quite many differences across platforms and backends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a [fix to this bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10338) on its way.

Until this finds its way into the next release of matplotlib, you may apply it manually. The solution is to add `line._invalidx = True` to force the line being recached.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(10, 24, 10)
y = np.random.randn(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
line, = ax.plot(x, y)
line.set_drawstyle("steps-pre") 
line._invalidx = True

plt.show()
```

Comment: it fixes the issue